# Shell Commands Using ( on Makefile

Tags: makefile

I'm preparing some latex files and decided to make some makefile to help me to compile and clean de latex files. So I created the following makefile

```
aula=listaProb
all: compile clean

compile:
    pdflatex $(aula).tex

clean:
    rm -rf !(makefile|$(aula).tex|$(aula).pdf) -v
```

But when I execute "make" I get the following mistake

```
rm -rf !(makefile|listaProb.tex|listaProb.pdf) -v
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
makefile:8: recipe for target 'clean' failed
make: *** [clean] Error 2
```

But the command

```
rm -rf !(makefile|listaProb.tex|listaProb.pdf) -v
```

works fine on the terminal. 
What is wrong? I can't find any mistake :/..

Ps. I use this way to remove the files because I want to delete all but the specified files. It needs the command

```
shopt -s extglob
```

before use it. If anyone knows how to do it without use extglob, it would be nice.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The problem is recipe commands are passed to `/bin/sh` which cannot process that syntax. You can change your Makefile to say:

```
clean:
    bash -O extglob -c "rm -rf !(makefile|$(aula).tex|$(aula).pdf) -v"
```

To force this command to be run in bash with `extglob` on.

Or define `SHELL` variable for your `make` e.g. by running:

```
make SHELL="/bin/bash -O extglob" clean
```

Or adding:

```
SHELL := /bin/bash -O extglob
```

To your make file. The former option only affects shell invocation of that one command, the latter will apply to all your recipes (commands).

Comment: @Ajob You're welcome. You may want to accept the answer to close the loop.